# Bash Echo command behaves unexpectedly in a while loop

Tags: mysql, bash, variables, while-loop, echo

I am in the process of cleaning up a user database for a client. I have the list of users that need to go, and am checking to see if they have any media that they've created before removing them.

This is a very simple script, and the problem is relatively minor. I'm sure it's obvious, I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
 12    while read each;
 13     do
 14
 15          query=$(mysql -u$username -p$password $database -e "select uid,nid,title from node where uid like '$each' limit 1;")
 16          if [[ -z $query ]]
 17              then query="No nodes"
 18          fi
 19          if [[ -z $query ]]
 20              then query="Error"
 21          fi
 22     echo -n "$each"
 23     echo -n " - "
 24     echo "$query"
 25     done <$source_file
```

The problem I'm experiencing is on line 22. I want a single line for each UID in the source file, in the following format:

```
UID - Query results
```

The problem I'm running into is that echoing `$each` only works if it is the only argument on the line. In the above example, the result looks like this:

```
 - Query results
```

(Forgive the quotes, but the hyphen is interpreted as a bullet on this forum if I don't quote it.)

If I place more than one variable or anything else on the same line as the first echo command, the `$each` variable returns empty. It will only display the variable's contents if it is on it's own line, or so it seems.

Further info:

1. The `$each` variable is an integer (as read from the file)
2. It doesn't matter how I parse it -- IE, if I enter `newvar="$each - $query"` and then `echo $newvar` the same thing occurs.
3. There is a slightly misleading comment above. `echo "$each "` (with a tailing space) overwrites one of the digits of the integer in `$each`.
4. If I place the `echo -n "$each"` line earlier in the code (after `do` but before the mysql query), the numbers display across the bottom of the output, like a ticker tape. This is by far the weirdest part for me, and I can provide a screenshot if that helps.

Comment: Your problem aside, why do you use three `echo`s? `echo "$each - $query"` would be much simpler (or use `printf` for maximum robustness and portability).

Comment: My problem aside, there is no reason to. I initially tried to do it in a single line, this was just for troubleshooting.  

Similarly, the double if statement is a relic of this script being used for another purpose previously -- If the first mysql query returned no results, try a second. If that one was also empty, throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$each` has a CR at the end. Strip it before using the variable.